# Magento 1.9.2.4 : Is there away to prevent any item from having an "Out of Stock" Status (regardless of quantity)?

Tags: stock, ce-1.9.2.4, out-of-stock, backorder

We have ways of dealing with 0 or sub zero quantity on items using backorder but it puts our customers off when they see an out of stock label.

I can put the whole catalog back in stock using the admin backend of course but everytime I upload stock levels and prices many items again appear out of stock.

Worse, I do not know if magento has a cron job to put more things out of stock as it finds them with zero levels.

I have tried obvious things like set min quantity for in stock to -100000 but it would not accept.

I could quite easily write a cron job to put everything in stock every 5 mins but that seems wrong. There must be a way to disable this without turning off stock management.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to disable stock management entirely.

To do so, you can go to **System > Configuration > Inventory > Product Stock Options section** and set **Manage Stock** to No.

Comment: Many thanks, and I have considered that but I need to know the quantity of each product so that for zero or low stock items at my supplier, I can advise customers that there would be a lead time for purchase. Would the quantity function still work? (... a little scared to turn it off just like that)

Comment: @alThePal no you're right it won't work as you won't be able to fill quantity. In that case what about enabling backorders. In the same section as I mentionned in my answer change **Backorder** to **Allow qty below 0**